# Pl/sql if statement

Tags: sql, plsql

I am familiar with tsql but not too familiar with plsql how can i get this query to work in pl sql?

```
DECLARE 
DATENUM INT := 1;

begin
 if DATENUM = 1 
        then 
             select 'one' as test from dual;
        else 
            select 'two' as test from dual;

end if;

end;
```

i just get the error below

```
[Error] Script lines: 1-15 -------------------------
 ORA-06550: line 7, column 14:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
ORA-06550: line 9, column 13:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
 Script line 7, statement line 7, column 14
```

eidt:

what i want to do is beable to run a query based on a condition

for example - if it is the first of the month then select * from stackdb
 if it is the 5th of the month then select * from adiffdb etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not due to the if statement, but to the fact that you need to specify a result variable to select the value in. Otherwise you would just be executing a dummy query.

```
DECLARE 
  DATENUM INT := 1;
  DATENAME varchar2(5);
begin
  if DATENUM = 1 then 
    select 'one' into DATENAME as test from dual;
  else 
    select 'two' into DATENAME as test from dual;
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: it was a really rough example, i really want it to run a query based on date, so each day can differ in query and sort

Comment: So.. What you asked for is actually not at all what you need? I'd be happy to help of course, but I wonder what kind of mind reading capabilities you expect me to have. :)

Comment: youre right, i put a better explanation up... i apologize trying to do 10 things at once

Comment: It doesn't make the question much clearer. It's still mainly about the error message, which I solved for you, I think. The additional part is basically a new question that also lack too much information to be answered. It's better to remove that from here and ask a new question with sufficient context.